# Can't navigate using Prism

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

I can't get the navigation in Prism to work. When I click on the buttons to go to respective views, nothing happens.

This is the Man View (Shell) XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMPractice2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/" 
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" 
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MVVMPractice2.Views"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"> 

        <Grid>
            <Button Margin="108,130,331.4,152.8" Content="View A" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ViewA"/>
            <Button Margin="254,130,185.4,152.8" Content="View B" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="ViewB"/>

            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion"/> <!--PRISM POWER-->
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

and its ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager; //PRISM POWER

    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; } 

    public MainWindowViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
    }

    private void Navigate(string uri)
    {
        regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", uri);
    }
}
```

and Bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper 
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {         
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(ViewA), "ViewA");
        Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(ViewB), "ViewB");

        Container.RegisterType<ICustomer, Customer>();
    }
}
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: I've not use the view model locator is Prism but is it struggling because it cannot find view models for your views?

Comment: I have the ViewModels for ViewA and ViewB. I can inculde them here if you want

Comment: Have you tried `RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ViewA")`? btw, registering a view for navigation is easier with `RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewType>()`...

Comment: Yes, I did it like that. But still it is not working :(

Comment: "Nothing" means `private void Navigate(string uri)` isn't executed or is it, but no navigation happens? In the latter case, do the views have actual content so you can distinguish them?

Comment: Yes, ViewA has the content as was in the MainWindow from my previous question earlier today, and ViewB as just one simple text label. If I set the break point in 'MainWindowViewModel' I see that it doesn't go through the constructor, nether through Navigate()

Comment: Are you using Prism 6.0?

Comment: Yes, and also according to this seminar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY&list=PLpKSP8oN83CnyCNFXUpyndzyGR-iSn-e3

Comment: My guess is your ViewModel can't be resolved by the ViewModel locator. There can be a few reasons: Namespaces do not match the expected pattern (they should be `MVVMPractice2.Views` and `MVVMPractice2.ViewModels`, if they differ you have to configure it yourself or use the default conventions. if the ViewModels are in different assembly you also need to do manual configuration. Last which do not seem to apply to you is that the View name = <Viewname>ViewModel convention (there have been a change to this convention in Prism 6 but only if the View was named `SomethingView`

Comment: Which namespaces are `MainWindow` and `MainWindowViewModel` in? Should be `Views` and `ViewModels`, respectively.

Comment: Yes, they are in the namespaces that you mentioned.

Comment: Just to mention that I added ViewA and ViewB as WPF Page, not as User Control

Comment: I just found out that if I step through ConfigureContainer() with debugger then at the end of the method I get ServiceLocator.cs not found. But Common Service Location gets installed automatically with Prism. If I run the application just normal, there is no exception. Just the navigation doesn't work

Comment: It works now. You were right! I had 'namespace MVVMPractice2.VIewModels' instead of 'namespace MVVMPractice2' for MainWindowViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got mine to work by using the `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` on UserControls only and not the window. I am assuming that you are using prism 6.

So what I did is, I first created the `MainWindow` that is going to house all my `UserControls`, I then created a `MainUserControl` that would house all the other UserControls. All this I achieved following this [blog post](http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/) (http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/). Remember to create your MVVM folders (View and ViewModel) folders with their respective contents as the blog highlights.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should expose `ICommand` to button's command property ,  not delegate command which is  concrete implementation of `ICommand`.

You can get rid of conventions of view model locator by implementing 
`ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver((viewType)` in application class startup overriden method.

For more info please search Brian Lagunas viewmodellocator blog

Comment: Whoever has downvoted can please give me a reason that I am wrong

Comment: Maybe Brian Lagunas can comment on it

Comment: Okay if I remove the link and replace it with actual answer you will remove the down vote?

Comment: Since I am new I didn't know link can't be posted

Comment: Why it got downvoted even after I removed the link really don't comprehend